# How to interface camera sensor to microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, raspberry-pi, gpio, camera

I want to make robotics vision project. Ideally one would want to go with [hi tier expensive sensors](https://www.ximea.com/pci-express-camera/pci-express-camera), they have no such problem, because they are interfaced directly to x64 CPU, via PCIe bus. Thus, raw pixel data can be easily further pushed, for example, to GPUs array, for really powerful processing schemes. Extremely straightforward thing, but very expensive.

To get started with some prototype, I would choose some cheaper sensor like [OV2710](https://www.ovt.com/sensors/OV2710-1E). But they have problem, between sensor itself and a cpu there exists some "malware layer" which ruins raw picture to MJPEG or something like this, as well as unwanted usb slave->cable->host.

I would like to do my own encoding/compressing scheme with some ARM cortex MC, for example raspberry PI. It has GPIO interface. I wish to unsolder all unnesesary USB stuff from that sensor, and wire it directly to the raspberry GPIO pins. Then cut central 512x512 pixels area, and have it in Pi RAM updated at 120fps. Can I do like that? Is there some "internal" raw sensor protocol? How is it called? Or should I go another way?

Comment: Can you just buy a CMU Cam and reprogram it?

Comment: There are already plenty of reasonably-priced sensors that interface directly to the RPi's camera port. What more do you need? You can combine a sensor with a Pi Zero for about $30, and program custom algorithms to your heart's content!

Comment: @DKNguyen First time hearing of it. Is it programmable o_O? They write that is has USB interface (and they say "its fastest"), but for me its 2x as limited, i need 2x more than that bus. It's stated that cam is 30 fps. I need exactly 120fps 512*512 32bit per sample data, it's 960MBaud, USB2 only can haz 480.. So I need to exterminate/eliminate/unsolder (maybe convenient for all) but crappy bottleneck interface between, and somehow force sensor to write directly to some kind of framebuffer. How to do that?

Comment: I saw that the CMU Cam is open source so...a 120FPS camera will be difficult to locate in general in a form that's easy to interface with. Writing to a framebuffer...you're starting to get into FPGA or video FIFO territory now. Maybe start a bit smaller.

Comment: @DaveTweed I want 2 cameras, and they have to be as fast as 2x960mbit/s. What is rpi camera port bandwidth? Doez it haz muxing capabilities to mux such flow?

Comment: Did you do any research at all before coming here? That kind of information is readily available. You're not going to get 32 bits, though. The highest resolution I've seen in a raw sensor is about 14 bits. High dynamic range is accomplished by taking multiple exposures.

Comment: @DaveTweed Do 32-bit ADCs even exist?

Comment: By the way, you do realize "haz" is cat speak, right?

Comment: @DaveTweed 10bit red+10bit greed+10bit blu = 30 bit per sample.. i choose nearest nice number 32. Yeah, i did research, but I was asking about some specific thing.. in a sensor like OV2710 - what is between sensor and usb slave logic? I cant find such info. Is there some kind of "internal protocol" that can poll sensor fast, but then incorporate it into slower USB? Is it modular? Can i get rid of USB and re-interface that CMOS sensor.. say it.. to PCIe, with means of FPGa and some maybe SRAM chips? or is it single module in single package, and you cant get rid of USB in any way?

Comment: @DKNguyen OV2710 is claimed to have 10 bit ADC, multiply that to 3 channels for RGB, and you' get 30 bit, which is near 32 bit. Also it is stated that it would stream VGA(640*480)@120.. just follow links for spec. I cant find info about what is between that sensor and USB, and can I get rid of internal processing, and reinterface it.. say it, to SRAM chip framebuffer on a custom-made PCB? Or is it a single package device, which cant be disassembled, and "USB things" just cant be ripped off (separated from) CMOS sensor, because it's one chip?

Comment: Where are you getting USB? The data you linked to does not mention it at all. It can do parallel interface or single-lane MIPI, and it uses SCCB for control.

Comment: @DaveTweed [Here, ofc](https://aliexpress.ru/af/OV2710.html) I want that CMOS sensor, with interface another than USB. What are my options?

Comment: And the sensor does not produce 3 channels of RGB data, it produces a single channel of Bayer-encoded data that you have to "demosaic" in order to get RGB.

Comment: @DaveTweed, Then we will have here 10bits * 4subpixels(probably RGBG?)*512*512*120fps.. Or I may even sacrifice 2 lower bits, to get 8bitsx4subpixels=32bits per debayesed sample. Anyway, I said all correctly. per sample i mean whole pixel, and it is 32bit for calculations.

Comment: You're looking in the wrong places. If you search for "OV2710 MIPI", you'll find all kinds of products (like [this one](https://www.arducam.com/product/1-2-7-color-cmos-ov2710-sensor-standalone-camera-uc2710-a25/)) that allow you to interface directly to the sensor.

Comment: There are no subpixels. There is just a total of 1080*1920 pixels, period.

Comment: @DaveTweed *support for one lane MIPI interface(up to 800 Mbps)* Ah! That was called mipi, and has *that* bandwidth. Great. Thanks, you've answered "internal raw interface question". Interestingly, can I interface that "directly" to x86-64 based cpu? ^_^ Like PCIe expansion card, that reads MIPI, acts like a MIPI host, or something like that?